# Very portable MIDI synth

Tags: piano, midi, synthesizer

I was planning to buy a very small MIDI keyboard ([akai lpk25](http://www.amazon.it/Akai-LPK25-Performance-Keyboard-Controller/dp/B002M8GBDI)).

Of course to make it produce sounds, I would need to connect it (via USB) to my laptop.

Question: say one day I want to go to the park and play a bit, is there something I can plug to the keyboard to make it output sound which is not my laptop (or mobile phone, since I don't have one)?
The smaller the merrier!

I am not sure how these things are called, I guess MIDI synths.

Comment: Search for "midi sound module". There are plenty.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what kind of sound the module should produce, but [Ketron](http://www.ketron.it/) produces some fairly portable ones.

Actually, have a look at this [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14631/how-to-use-my-mac-and-midi-keyboard-as-a-simple-always-on-piano), has many more examples.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is synthesizer, not MIDI controller. You can search with this way.

An example; you can check how suitable Yamaha Piaggero 61-Key Lightweight Compact is for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few portable, miniature polyphonic keyboard synthesizers available.

The [Casio SA-76](http://www.casiomusicgear.com/products/menu_mini/SA-76) is one; it sells for US $50. It has built-in speakers and runs on batteries; however, it does not have MIDI.

[image]

Another model, if it is still on the market, is the [CME U-Key v2 Mobiltone](http://www.cme-pro.com/proline/product-detail.php-product_id=17.htm), which does have MIDI, and a built-in speaker, but it does not run on batteries. It requires USB bus-power.

[image]

Korg has just announced a new product, the [tinyPIANO](http://www.korg.com/us/products/digitalpianos/tinypiano), a digital toy piano that runs on batteries. (Hey, you asked for it.) It does not have MIDI.

[image]